# Suspicious link on android

Tags: applications, malware, vpn, dns

I accidentaly clicked on http://127.0.0.1:5555 this link on my android phone what should i do? i don't know anything about coding so please write with simple words to me

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is the address of your phone itself. Therefore everything that can be loaded have to be generated by an app or an system service of Android on your phone. If there is no app listening on port 5555 then nothing will happen, the web browser will simply show an error page.

Therefore you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is a loopback device... Meaning it is going back to itself (your own phone, 127.0.0.1 is your own device's internal address). Port 5555 is used by VPN's for transmitting and receiving encrypted traffic, so basically you clicked a link that redirected your request back to itself, or in other words it did nothing. You should be safe, malware is much less common than people want you to believe.